# FAQ: divide #how-to-ask into #how-to-ask and #how-to-accept-answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There is a nice image manual to FAQ entry `#howtoask`, it would better to create new entry named `#howtoacceptanswer` and move there a part of `#howtoask`

Because people usually know how to lay down question, they can learn syntax of formatting question/answer, but sometimes not what to do if they got the right answer

and second, if pointing to `how to accept answer`, i use link https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask but in that time, user who asks already knows how to literally `ask`

Comment: You can also use http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work as a link to show new users the process of accepting an answer.

Comment: @jonsca: great tip :)